# Nuxt / Vue.js delayed styling on initial render or page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

As the title suggests, I've noticed something peculiar while working with Nuxt/Vue, and I'm relatively new to it.

The styling of all components appears to be loading unusually slowly during rendering, even though I'm in a "dev" environment. I'm curious about what might be causing this and how I can address it. I've extensively searched the internet for answers but haven't found any yet.

We are using SCSS for the styling, in the "style" component of Vue.

Demostration:
Demonstation bug: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkGvY.gif)

I tried to solve it by using the component NuxtLoadingIndicator and other transitions that should help with the loading, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Does this only happen in development or also in build?

Comment: We have not made a build yet, this is the dev environment

Comment: Could be that its only an issue with dev. I also had slow loading styles in my dev but in build it was fine

Comment: I just found out you are right, i ran a build and after that i previewed it. And the "bug" is not appearing on production

Comment: If you are using SCSS maybe you are generating a main css file for your project. Have you tried to preload this css? Something like `<link rel="preload" href="main.css" as="style">`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an upstream bug from Vite which was fixed in v5.1.3 ref: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/25860

You can add a resolution/override for now:

```json
// package.json for pnpm
{
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "vite": "^5.1.3"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
// package.json for npm
{
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "overrides": {
    "vite": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

```json
// package.json for yarn
{
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "resolutions": {
    "vite": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Or it will be fixed in the next Nuxt patch release.